# How to calulate sum orginalprice discountprice android

Tags: android

I have tried original price discount price and I am getting error.how to slove this problem. **vItem.price.setText(p.price);  ** this realprice  **vItem.discountprice.setText(p.discountprice);**this discount price.[image]

```
public class AdapterHomeRecipes extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    private List<Recipe> items;

    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    private Context context;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    boolean scrolling = false;

    private SharedPref sharedPref;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, Recipe obj, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public AdapterHomeRecipes(Context context, RecyclerView view, List<Recipe> items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
        this.sharedPref = new SharedPref(context);
        lastItemViewDetector(view);
        view.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    scrolling = true;
                } else if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    scrolling = false;
                }
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
        });
    }




     public class OriginalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
            public TextView category_name;
            public TextView recipe_title;
            public ImageView recipe_image;
            public ImageView thumbnail_video;
            public MaterialRippleLayout lyt_parent;
            public TextView price;
            public TextView discountprice;
            public TextView discountpricetext;
    
            public OriginalViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                category_name = v.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
                recipe_title = v.findViewById(R.id.recipe_title);
                recipe_image = v.findViewById(R.id.recipe_image);
                thumbnail_video = v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_video);
                lyt_parent = v.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent);
                price = v.findViewById(R.id.price);
                discountprice = v.findViewById(R.id.discountprice);
                discountpricetext = v.findViewById(R.id.discountpricetext);
            }
    
        }
    
        public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public ProgressBar progressBar;
    
            public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                progressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.load_more);
            }
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
            if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_home_recipe, parent, false);
                vh = new OriginalViewHolder(v);
            } else {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_load_more, parent, false);
                vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
            }
            return vh;
        }
    
        // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            if (holder instanceof OriginalViewHolder) {
                final Recipe p = items.get(position);
                final OriginalViewHolder vItem = (OriginalViewHolder) holder;
    
                vItem.category_name.setText(p.category_name);
                vItem.recipe_title.setText(p.recipe_title);
    
                vItem.price.setPaintFlags(vItem.price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    
                vItem.price.setText(p.price);
    
                vItem.discountprice.setText(p.discountprice);
    
                int discount = p.price - p.discountprice);
                float discountPercentage = ( (float) discount / price ) * 100;
    
    
                vItem.discountpricetext.setText(discountPercentage);
    
    
    
    
    
    
                if (p.content_type != null && p.content_type.equals("youtube")) {
                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(Constant.YOUTUBE_IMAGE_FRONT + p.video_id + Constant.YOUTUBE_IMAGE_BACK_MQ)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail)
                            .into(vItem.recipe_image);
                } else {
                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(sharedPref.getApiUrl() + "/upload/" + p.recipe_image)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail)
                            .into(vItem.recipe_image);
                }
    
                if (p.content_type != null && p.content_type.equals("Post")) {
                    vItem.thumbnail_video.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    vItem.thumbnail_video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
    
                vItem.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                    if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                        mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, p, position);
                    }
                });
    
            } else {
                ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            }
    
            if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_PROG) {
                StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
            } else {
                StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.setFullSpan(false);
            }
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return items.size();
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (items.get(position) != null) {
                return VIEW_ITEM;
            } else {
                return VIEW_PROG;
            }
        }
    
        public void insertData(List<Recipe> items) {
            setLoaded();
            int positionStart = getItemCount();
            int itemCount = items.size();
            this.items.addAll(items);
            notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
        }
    
        public void setLoaded() {
            loading = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
                if (items.get(i) == null) {
                    items.remove(i);
                    notifyItemRemoved(i);
                }
            }
        }
    
        public void setLoading() {
            if (getItemCount() != 0) {
                this.items.add(null);
                notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
                loading = true;
            }
        }
    
        public void resetListData() {
            this.items = new ArrayList<>();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    
        public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
            this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
        }
    
        private void lastItemViewDetector(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    
            if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
                final StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                        int lastPos = getLastVisibleItem(layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPositions(null));
                        if (!loading && lastPos == getItemCount() - 1 && onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                            int current_page = getItemCount() / AppConfig.POST_PER_PAGE;
                            onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore(current_page);
                            loading = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    
        public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
            void onLoadMore(int current_page);
        }
    
        private int getLastVisibleItem(int[] into) {
            int last_idx = into[0];
            for (int i : into) {
                if (last_idx < i) last_idx = i;
            }
            return last_idx;
        }
    
    }
    `
```

model this model class below public String price; public String discountprice; show server

```
 public class Recipe implements Serializable {
    
        public int id;
    
        public String cat_id;
        public String category_name;
        public long name=1;
        public long recipe_id = -1;
        public String recipe_title;
        public String recipe_time;
    
        public String price;
    
        public String discountprice;
    
        public String recipe_image;
        public String recipe_description;
        public String video_url;
        public String video_id;
        public String content_type;
        public String featured;
        public String tags;
        public long total_views;
        public long comments_count = -1;
    
        public Recipe() {
        }
    
        public Recipe(long recipe_id) {
            this.recipe_id = recipe_id;
        }
    
    
        public Recipe(String category_name, long recipe_id, String recipe_title, String recipe_time,String price,String discountprice, String recipe_image, String recipe_description, String video_url, String video_id, String content_type, String featured, String tags, long total_views) {
            this.category_name = category_name;
            this.recipe_id = recipe_id;
            this.recipe_title = recipe_title;
            this.recipe_time = recipe_time;
            this.price = price;
            this.discountprice = discountprice;
            this.recipe_image = recipe_image;
            this.recipe_description = recipe_description;
            this.video_url = video_url;
            this.video_id = video_id;
            this.content_type = content_type;
            this.featured = featured;
            this.tags = tags;
            this.total_views = total_views;
            this.comments_count = comments_count;
        }
    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getCat_id() {
            return cat_id;
        }
    
        public void setCat_id(String cat_id) {
            this.cat_id = cat_id;
        }
    
        public String getCategory_name() {
            return category_name;
        }
    
        public void setCategory_name(String category_name) {
            this.category_name = category_name;
        }
    
        public long getRecipe_id() {
            return recipe_id;
        }
    
        public void setRecipe_id(long recipe_id) {
            this.recipe_id = recipe_id;
        }
    
        public String getRecipe_title() {
            return recipe_title;
        }
    
        public void setRecipe_title(String recipe_title) {
            this.recipe_title = recipe_title;
        }
    
        public String getRecipe_time() {
            return recipe_time;
        }
    
        public void setRecipe_time(String recipe_time) {
            this.recipe_time = recipe_time;
        }
    
    
        public String getprice() {
            return price;
        }
    
        public void setprice(String price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
    
        public String getdiscountprice() {
            return discountprice;
        }
    
        public void setdiscountprice(String discountprice) {
            this.discountprice = discountprice;
        }
    
    
    
    
        public String getRecipe_image() {
            return recipe_image;
        }
    
        public void setRecipe_image(String recipe_image) {
            this.recipe_image = recipe_image;
        }
    
        public String getRecipe_description() {
            return recipe_description;
        }
    
        public void setRecipe_description(String recipe_description) {
            this.recipe_description = recipe_description;
        }
    
        public String getVideo_url() {
            return video_url;
        }
    
        public void setVideo_url(String video_url) {
            this.video_url = video_url;
        }
    
        public String getVideo_id() {
            return video_id;
        }
    
        public void setVideo_id(String video_id) {
            this.video_id = video_id;
        }
    
        public String getContent_type() {
            return content_type;
        }
    
        public void setContent_type(String content_type) {
            this.content_type = content_type;
        }
    
        public String getFeatured() {
            return featured;
        }
    
        public void setFeatured(String featured) {
            this.featured = featured;
        }
    
        public String getTags() {
            return tags;
        }
    
        public void setTags(String tags) {
            this.tags = tags;
        }
    
        public long getTotal_views() {
            return total_views;
        }
    
        public void setTotal_views(long total_views) {
            this.total_views = total_views;
        }
        public long getComments_count() {
            return comments_count;
        }
    
        public void setComments_count(long comments_count) {
            this.comments_count = comments_count;
        }
    }
```

calulate sum orginalprice  discountprice android update model class

Comment: You have several errors in the screenshot you posted. Where are price and discountprice defined? Also, when you are setting text it expects a String data type and not a float data type. You need to convert it to a string.

Comment: @tomerpacific  i am new android devloper how to include sir

Comment: Where to include what? Please edit your question with the missing details.

Comment: @tomerpacific  update code plz show code

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is caused by the fact that you are trying to set a float value to a string value.

You have your TextView called `discountpricetext` and you are using it's method setText. [SetText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) can accepts several types of arguments, but it cannot accept a float type.

Therefore, to resolve your problem, you need to convert the data to string.

I.E.

```
vItem.discountpricetext.setText(discountPercentage.toString());
```

Comment: https://postimg.cc/qtXP1WXF  not clear error bro

Comment: @jayram - The error you are showing indicates that the two elements you are trying to subtract are strings... You need to convert them.

Comment: how to change bro

Comment: Operator '-' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'java.lang.String' show

Comment: to elements how to change 
int discount = p.price - p.discountprice);

Comment: @jayram - Convert the string to either an int/float. Be forewarned that the methods may throw an exception if the string is not in a valid format. [Reference](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/java-string-to-int-how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer/).

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/QxH2yzYD/Screenshot-125.png

Comment: coding error bro